# Embedded youtube video in website gives error in Chrome while logged into Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, live

Any website that embeds a You Tube live stream give me an error message (see below)  "This Live Event No Longer Available" in Chrome, only if I'm signed into Chrome.  If I sign out of Chrome, or go incognito, the same embedded livestream plays fine.  I have reloaded Chrome, deleted all cookies, no help.  [image: screen shot of error]

Comment: Probably an error from YouTube itself. Consider post this issue at [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and so far signing out of youtube/chrome/gmail or to go incognito is the only solution.